# Creating custom function in wordpress to return data from database

Tags: theme-development, functions

I have created a custom image uploader for my wordpress admin panel and need to retrieve the data from the wp_options table. I have wrritne the below function:

```
//function to get all slider images
function getSliderImages(){
global $wpdb, $theme_shortname;
$query = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->options AS o1 
WHERE o1.option_name LIKE '%".$theme_shortname."_header_image%'";
$imgs = $wpdb->get_results($query);

$images = array();
//loop through images and remove unusable results
foreach($imgs as $i){
    $id = substr($i['option_name'],0,-1);
    if(is_numeric($id)){
        $images[] = $i['option_value'];
    }
}

return($images);
}
```

How do I access the returned array in header.php on the front end? this function is currently in themes/themename/functions.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your header.php

```
$images = getSliderImages();
    foreach ( $images as $img ) {
        echo '<img src="' .$img. '" />';
    }
```

Comment: This was the way i tried it first but I get this error from the function.

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /Users/wadem/Sites/gpsite/wp-content/themes/PracticeInABox/functions.php on line 747 

The line it refers to is

$id = substr($i['option_name'],0,-1);

Comment: Try `$id = substr( $->option_name, 0,1 );`